# Network- Create edges between one node and a list of nodes

Tags: nodes, networkx, edges

I am brand new to networkx and can't figure out how read my specific formatting of data.

I have some data that looks like (node, list of nodes that it's connected to), like so:

```
('person 1', 'person 2, person 3, person 4')
```

I want to add edges so that they look like this:

```
('person 1', 'person 2')
('person 1', 'person 3')
('person 1', 'person 4')
```

Is there a way to specify the first node, and iterate over a list to get the rest of the nodes? In my csv file, one column is the primary node, and the second column is a list of nodes it's connected to, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to add them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Although there's no bultin method, you can use Python slices and list comprehension to add them in one line.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
nodes = list("ABCD")
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from([(nodes[0],node) for node in nodes[1:]])
```

nodes[1:] is a list with the first item skipped

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question (since I finally figured it out):

first I had to string split the second column to get the individual names, with the separator "," or ", " with a space.

```
MyData$2ndColumn = strsplit(MyData$2ndColumn, ", |,")
```

Then I used unnest to separate it into four different entries, as requested in the question

```
MyData <- unnest(MyData)
```